# I am non-EU citizen working as a volunteer in Denmark, can I travel within the Schengen Area without visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, russian-citizens, denmark, volunteering

I'm a non-EU citizen (Russian) working as a volunteer in Denmark and have received a Danish residence permit (type J), valid until December. Can I travel within the Schengen Area without visa right now?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a residence permit from one Schengen country implicitly gives you the rights to travel within/through the rest of the Schengen area much as if you had a multiple-entry short-stay visa.

You have to comply with the usual 90/180 day rule for days you're in a Schengen country that is not Denmark, but enforcement of this is mostly by the honor system since your passport won't get stamped when traveling between Schengen countries.

Comment: Just a note that with the current/on-going migration crises happening all over Europe (mostly to the South), there may be more "random" stops and/or checkpoints at various borders. This doesn't change the answer as given, but just be aware.